# Backfill Beam pipeline with historical data

Tags: apache-beam, google-dataflow

I have a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline (written with the Apache Beam SDK) that, in its normal mode of operation, handles event data published to Cloud Pub/Sub.

In order to bring the pipeline state up to date, and to create the correct outputs, there is a significant amount of historical event data which must be processed first. This historical data is available via JDBC. In testing, I am able to use the `JdbcIO.Read` PTransform to read and handle all historical state, but I'd like to initialize my production pipeline using this JDBC event data, and then cleanly transition to reading events from Pub/Sub. This same process may happen again in the future if the pipeline logic is ever altered in a backward incompatible way.

Note that while this historical read is happening, new events are continuing to arrive into Pub/Sub (and these end up in the database also), so there should be a clean cutover from only historical events read from JDBC, and only newer events read from Pub/Sub.

Some approaches I have considered:

1. Have a pipeline that reads from both inputs, but filters data from JDBC before a certain timestamp, and from pub/sub after a certain timestamp. Once the pipeline is caught up deploy an update removing the JDBC input.

   I don't think this will work because removal of an I/O transform is not backward compatible. Alternately, the JDBC part of the pipeline must stay there forever, burning CPU cycles for no good reason.
2. Write a one-time job that populates pub/sub with the entirety of the historical data, and then starts the main pipeline reading only from pub/sub.

   This seems to use more pub/sub resources than necessary, AND I think newer data interleaved in the pipeline with much older data will cause watermarks to be advanced too early.
3. Variation of option #2 -- stop creating new events until the historical data is handled, to avoid messing up watermarks.

   This requires downtime.

It seems like it would be a common requirement to backfill historical data into a pipeline, but I haven't been able to find a good approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option, reading from a Bounded source (filtered to timestamp <= cutoff) and PubSub (filtered to timestamp > cutoff) should work well.

Because JDBC.Read() is a bounded source, it will be read all the data and then "finish" i.e. never produce any more data, advance its watermark to +infinity, and not be invoked again (so there's no concern about it consuming CPU cycles, even if it's present in your graph).

Comment: When reading from JDBC, all timestamps will by default be -infinity. How are timers being used?

Comment: I'm looking into some issues with Google Dataflow support, but I don't think these are related to the general approach, which seems like it should work. Thanks.